# Google Hangouts Chat API IP to Whitelist?

Tags: google-hangouts

I am building a bot that will interact with the Google Hangouts Chat API. I need to punch a hole in my firewall to receive incoming HTTPS requests.

Is there a subnet I can expect Google to send requests from? I would rather not open the bot to the entire world.

For organizational reasons, we cannot use pub/sub endpoints. We just need an ip or ip range from google to whitelist

Comment: Best I could find was [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1279090) which suggests doing an `nslookup` on their `_netblocks.google.com` to their DNS 8.8.8.8 for a list of IP's they are using. I would imagine the list changes.

Comment: It looks like we can build a solution from this. Thank you!